# Access Database Update in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

So I have 2 access databases, 1 has data, the other one has no data but contains all the tables and columns that the other database has and more. What I need to do is to grab all the columns from each of the tables in the second database, and add them if they are missing in the 1st database. How would you go about accomplishing this? I have looked online, but I can't find examples of this specific scenario. I've found it where people add columns to databases but they are specific and known.

I need to write this in C#, and using different database sets.

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools; Tools -> SQL Server -> "New Schema Comparison..." and produce a diff script from there. There are also various third-party tools, of course. I would *not* write my own code for this (although you certainly *can*, using SMO or even T-SQL if you're feeling particularly masochistic).

Comment: Well, I'm trying to write a tool in c# that will do this for different database sets. So a one time script is no good to me if I have to produce a new script every time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert does it work with MS-Access?

Comment: Whoops, I completely skipped over the multiple mentions of Access, for some reason. No, the SQL Server Data Tools are (unsurprisingly) specific to SQL Server.

Comment: @JosephThompson you need to work with OleDbConnection.GetSchema and its constraints. Take all the tables, loop over them and take all the columns of each table, check if the column exists in the destination table, update and continue. Not complex but very tedious and error prone.

Comment: @Steve you can use SSIS and it works with ms-access and any kind of input data to produce an output that goes directly to another database